# CSS3 circular movement doesn't work in chrome with @-webkit-keyframes, and works with @keyframes in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

Here is the circle which is NOT animated by `orbit` in Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/ztkav838/

```
//CSS
@-webkit-keyframes orbit
{
    from{transform:rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);}
    to{transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);}
}
.round_btn
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius:50% !important;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    width:30px !important;
    height:30px !important;
}
.satellite
{
    animation:orbit 16s linear infinite;   
}
<div data-role="button" class="round_btn satellite"></div>
```

When I replace `@webkit-keyframes` with `@keyframes` it works in Firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/mye6mg49/

```
//CSS
@keyframes orbit
{
    from{transform:rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);}
    to{transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);}
}
.round_btn
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius:50% !important;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    width:30px !important;
    height:30px !important;
}
.satellite
{
    animation:orbit 16s linear infinite;   
}
//HTML
<div data-role="button" class="round_btn satellite"></div>
```

Changing `transform` to `webkit-transform` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add -webkit-animation like this:-

```
.satellite
{
  animation: orbit 16s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: orbit 16s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add -webkit- prefixes for keyframe rule and animation, Try this updated demo.